# How to best handle errors in ExpressJS POST routes

Tags: angularjs, express

I am currently struggling with best practices for error handling in ExpressJS routes, particularly POST routes.

I have set up the default middleware error handling and I am using `return next(err);` in case of any errors. This works fine for all errors in GET routes.

However, what is the best practice to handle errors in the other route types, in particular POST routes?

On the front end, I am using AngularJS and I am posting using `$http`. When using `return next(err);` in the POST route, the `.error(function(data,status,headers,config)` of `$http` is called (AngularJS) and I receive the whole html error page inside data variable.

What I am looking for is a redirect for the user to the general error page through the ExpressJS middleware in case the client-side should not handle this error. This way, I could also do my error handling and logging at one single place.

So, my current idea: In POST routes, simply do `return res.status(500).send({err: err});` In case the application cannot recover, then use a redirect on client side with AngularJS to a general error page. However, I would prefer to use the ExpressJS middleware to have a central place to handle errors.

I appreciate any help or pointers to best practice articles!

For reference, the (standard) error middleware function looks like this:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('shared/error/error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: err
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an angular $http method to GET or POST to your server, you should be returning JSON data back to the app to parse. For example, your route:

```
app.get('/example', function(req, res) {
    getSomeData()
        .then(function(data) {
            res.status(200).json(data);
        }, function(err) {
            res.status(400).json(err);
        });
});
```

In your angular service, you can create a method that returns the route's data in a promise:

```
angularApp.service('DataService', function($http) {
    this.getData = function() {
         return $http.get('/example')
    };
});
```

Then use the service in your controller like this:

```
angularApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, DataService) {

    DataService.getData()
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
        }, function(err) {
            showErrorMessage(err.statusText);
        });
});
```

Comment: Hello Blu! Thank you for your detailed answer regarding error handling in AngularJS. To clarify: For GET routes, I would like to use the ExpressJS error handling middleware which is working fine. I am now wondering if I can use the same mechanism for errors in POST routes or if it is actually the best practice to handle those errors directly in AngularJS.

Comment: For POST routes, the method would be the same as above, but with app.get() replaced with app.post() and $http.get() replaced with $http.post(). The only discernible difference between the two routes is that GET is meant for retrieving data from the database, and POST is meant for creating data.

Comment: Blu, thanks again! I think I did not express my point clearly enough. Please let me try again. For GET routes, one established and good way to handle errors is directly through the ExpressJS middleware (using return next(err);). Is there a similar way to handle errors for POST routes in ExpressJS directly?

Comment: In your error middleware function you're using res.render, which will take the data provided and _compile_ a template you provide into html. Since POST requests are designed to return data, not page content; I'd say you probably can't and shouldn't do that.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your comments! I am still wondering a little why there are no articles about handling errors in POST routes directly in ExpressJS using its middleware, but for now I will just split error handling depending on the route types.